# How to rigorously prove that if $A\times B\neq\emptyset$ then $(A\times B\subset X\times Y)\iff(A\subset X)\land (B\subset Y)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, alternative-proof

I want to prove this formula as rigorous as possible.
Here is my proof.

$\Rightarrow)$

We need to prove that
$(A\not\subset X\lor B\not\subset Y)\land (A\times B\neq \emptyset)\Rightarrow A\times B\not\subset X\times Y$.

1. $A\not\subset X\land A\times B\neq\emptyset\Rightarrow\exists a\ a\in A\land a\notin X\ \land\ \exists s\ s\in A\times B \\ \Rightarrow a_0\in A\land a_0\notin X\land s_0\in A\times B\Rightarrow a_0\in A\land a_0\notin X\land\exists a\exists b\ a\in A\land b\in B\land s_0=(a,b) \\ 
   \Rightarrow a_0\in A\land a_0\notin X\land a_1\in A\land b_1\in B\land s_0=(a_1,b_1)\\
   \Rightarrow (a_0,b_1)\in A\times B\land (a_0,b_1)\notin X\times Y\Rightarrow\exists e\ e\in A\times B\land e\notin X\times Y\Rightarrow A\times B\not\subset X\times Y$
2. $B\not\subset Y\land A\times B\neq\emptyset\Rightarrow A\times B\not\subset X\times Y$

$\Leftarrow)$

$A\times B\not\subset X\times Y\Rightarrow \exists s\ s\in A\times B\land s\notin X\times Y \\
\Rightarrow s_0\in A\times B\land s_0\notin X\times Y\Rightarrow (\exists a\exists b\ a\in A \land b\in B\land s_0 = (a,b))\land s_0\notin X\times Y\\ \Rightarrow a_0\in A\land b_0\in B\land s_0 = (a_0,b_0)\land s_0\notin X\times Y \Rightarrow a_0\in A\land b_0\in B\land(a_0,b_0)\notin X\times Y\\
\Rightarrow a_0\in A\land b_0\in B\land (a_0\notin X \lor b_0\notin Y)\\
\Rightarrow (a_0\in A\land b_0\in B\land a_0\notin X)\lor(a_0\in A\land b_0\in B\land b_0\notin Y)\Rightarrow(\exists a\ a\in A\land a\notin X)\lor(\exists b\ b\in B\land b\notin Y)\\
\Rightarrow(A\not\subset X)\lor(B\not\subset Y)$

I'm pretty sure that, conceptually, this proof is correct. However, I might have accidentally skipped some steps, and, as for the others, I cannot fully justify them. So, can anyone correct this proof and provide its rigorous version?

Comment: Why do you artificially insist on showing $(A\not\subset X)\lor(B\not\subset Y)\iff(A\times B\not\subset X\times Y)$ instead of attacking $(A\times B\subset X\times Y)\iff(A\subset X)\land (B\subset Y)$ directly?

Comment: Also, I totally agree with our "I cannot fully justify them". While your proof essentially does the right thing, you *justified* none of your steps. Besides, Maximizing the density of formal symbols to 100% is not the same as being as rigorous as possible; legibility is also appreciated.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen, as for the first question, I have proved the contrapositive cause I was stuck while proving directly. As for the second, do you mean I should specify which rules I apply in each step? I thought they were clear enough. The question is whether I used them rightfully and didn't miss any step. Anyway, thanks for the handy hint.